# ScrollView minHeight to take up all the space

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-native-flexbox

I have a `ScrollView` which content doesn't necessarily exceeds it's size. Let's say it's a form where, upon errors, it expands to add error messages and then it exceeds the `ScrollView` size and thus is why I'm using that scroll.

The thing is that I want the content to always be at least of the same size of the ScrollView. I'm aware of the `minHeight` property, but the only way I found to use it is re-rendering, which I'd like to avoid.

I'm using redux for state management and this is what I have

```html
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={[ownStyles.container, {minHeight: this.props.scrollHeight}]}
  style={this.props.style}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  onLayout={(event) => {
    scrollHeight = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    this.props.setScrollContentHeight(scrollHeight);
  }}
>
```

Where the `this.props.setScrollContentHeight` triggers an action which enters the height on the state, and `this.props.scrollHeight` is said height. So that after the first render where the onLayout function is triggered, the state is updated with the ScrollView's `height`, which I then assign as `minHeight` to its content.

If I set the content's style to `flex: 1` then the ScrollView won't scroll.

Can you think of a way to avoid that second render for performance purposes?

Thank you!

Comment: and using `height: 100%;` doesn't do the job?

Comment: refer this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3422

Answer (score 25):

You should use `flexGrow: 1` for the ScrollView and `flex: 1` inside the ScrollView, to get a ScrollAble but at least as big as possible `<View>`.

There has been a [discussion about it in react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4099) and [tushar-singh](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4099#issuecomment-307541206) had the great idea to it.

Comment: Be careful that for ScrollView you cannot use style directly but contentContainerStyle: `<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>`

Comment: Also, if your inner view is a KeyboardAvoidingView like mine was, you'll need to use <KeyboardAvoidingView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} style={{flex: 1}}> (or, at least I did).

Answer (score 17):

It has been a long time but I struggled with the same issue. The easy way to do it is to use `flexGrow: 1` instead of `flex:1` on both scrollView's `style` and `contentContainerStyle` props. The content will take at least 100% of space and more if needed.

Comment: THX! However `contentContainerStyle` was enough for me

Answer (score 13):

A couple of solutions of doing this are:

- Use a `minHeight` on the `ScrollView` (but this requires taking into account the screen dimension to render correctly)
- Use a `flexGrow: 1` on the `ScrollView` `contentContainerStyle` and a `flex: 1` to the inner content:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    ...
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 7):

i want to share my solution, for me nothing of https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4099 worked. Also i cannot comment there because facebook blocked the thread ¬.¬ !

Basically my solution is set `flexGrow: 1` in `contentContainerStyle` on the `ScrollView` component, and wrap all the content inside in a `View` component with a `height` property setted with the screen size. Here the example code:

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
   <View style={{height: screenHeight}}>
    ... your content here ...
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but I think wrapping the contents inside of that `ScrollView` with a `View` with `minHeight` style property will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    Your content
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

That worked for me.